# My min() method doesnt work as expected (python)

Tags: python

I need help explaining this. The bug happens at the seventh line (`smallest_1 = min(list(three))`). I don't understand why when I try to get min() from "three" (a list) that the min() element get deleted from the list ("three") (like pop()). I don't usually use min() for a list but I believe this is not how it works.

I don't mind about a bad solution. I am just trying to get my head around recursion, since I always have a hard time understanding and using it.

```
def sum_two_smallest_numbers(numbers, index = 0, two = []):
    """This function return sum of two smallest number in an array"""
    if index == 0:
        two = [numbers[0], numbers[1]]
        index += 2
    if index < len(numbers) and index >= 2:
        three = list(two + [numbers[index]])
        smallest_1 = min(list(three))
        smallest_2 = min(three.remove(smallest_1))
        two = [smallest_1, smallest_2]
        return sum_two_smallest_numbers(numbers, index + 1, two)
    return sum(two)
print(sum_two_smallest_numbers([7, 15, 12, 18, 22]))
```

Comment: `min(three.remove(smallest_1))` won't work because `list.remove` returns `None` - it will give a *TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable*

Comment: No i mean the line  (smallest_1 = min(list(three))) already did the remove job. i ran debug.  and tried to delete the (smallest_2 = min(three.remove(smallest_1))) line

Comment: Note: this sort of recursion resembles doing a very poor for loop: think about it: the "recursive" part is about passing down the loop index. Conceptually, this is really NOT how you would ever want to use recursion.

Comment: Also thanks for min(three.remove(smallest_1)) won't work because list.remove returns None, i dont know that

Comment: @RandomName you're welcome. Most `list` methods *change* the list in some way and return `None`

Comment: ty ghostcat, like i said i wont use recusion for this type of problem, its just a practice

Comment: I understand, just saying: it might make more sense to practice on a more reasonable problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your program works fine except that one problem with removing element from list, look:

```
l = [1,2,3]
print(l.remove(1)) # None
print(l) # [2,3]
```

So `list.remove()` modifies **mutable** list and doesn't return new one like in case of e.g. **immutable** strings

```
s = "abc"
print(s.upper()) # ABC
print(s) # abc
```

Saying that, move removing element from the list into separate line

```
three.remove(smallest_1)
smallest_2 = min(three)
```

As a bonus, I am pretty sure you know it can be done better in many ways, but as simple code improvment - **why not to delete `max` from three?**

Comment: hehehehe, thanki, i dont know what is with my head. just dumb

Answer (score 0):

The only problem was the `three.remove(smallest_1)`.

Change this and it becomes:

```py
def sum_two_smallest_numbers(numbers, index=0, two=[]):
    if index == 0:
        two = [numbers[0], numbers[1]]
        index += 2
    if index < len(numbers) and index >= 2:
        three = two + [numbers[index]]
        smallest_1 = min(three)
        three.remove(smallest_1)
        smallest_2 = min(three)
        two = [smallest_1, smallest_2]
        return sum_two_smallest_numbers(numbers, index+1, two)
    return sum(two)

print(sum_two_smallest_numbers([7, 15, 12, 18, 22]))
```

Output: `19`

---

Some improvements:

```py
def sum_two_smallest_numbers(nums, index=0, two=[]):
    if not index: # equivalent to if index == 0
        two = nums[:2] # rather than [nums[0], nums[1]]
        index = 2
    if index < len(nums):
        three = two + [nums[index]]
        three.remove(max(three)) # Remove max rather than add two min
        return sum_two_smallest_numbers(nums, index+1, three)
    return sum(two)
```

Comment: wow, so nice havent thought abt it